# What is the origin of "odds and ends"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, british-english

There's already a question (and answer) for ["bits and bobs"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4942/bibs-and-bobs-what-does-it-mean-and-where-does-it-come-from), which I believe is a Britishism, but what is the origin of "odds and ends"?  "Odds" I have some reckoning for (as in, "odd items", meaning leftover).  Why is this specie of miscellanea paired with "ends"?

Additionally, is "odds and ends" an Americanism?

Comment: Why should *ends* not mean "leftovers" too -- in a similar meaning to "End of line" for obsolescent stock? *Odds and ends* is certainly not limited to American English, but it's now late and I can't be bothered to look it up. What did a dictionary or etymonline or phrases.org tell you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This phrase is older than you might imagine, having its roots in Anglo-Saxon. It is a corruption of *ord and ende* as indicated here in *Folk-etymology: a dictionary of verbal corruptions or words perverted in form or meaning, by false derivation or mistaken*, by Abram Smythe Palmer:

[image]

The original expression meant "points and ends" which "signifies beginning and end."

Comment: It's at the margins of my vocabulary, but [orts](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZmqM6qW-3JcC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=orts+fragments+victuals&source=bl&ots=MQ_9rlf78D&sig=KvCfIPmHv1u9aLR5Z9Ku1nT3pMc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZlmHUP3zNsi-0QWAnoC4BA&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=orts%20fragments%20victuals&f=false) is just about there. Once in a blue moon you need it for a crossword!