# Looking for a single term to describe items that a person carries with them everyday (e.g. phone, wallet, keys, etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

I'm trying to find a term for items that are commonly carried every day such as phone, wallet and keys.

"Everyday Items" doesn't quite seem to carry to connotation I'm looking for as it makes me think of a broader range of items that would also include dish soap, towels, forks, ect.

"Personal effects" is fairly accurate, however, it feels a bit archaic for the context I'm trying to use it.

Preferably this would be a single word or two-word term.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Pocket fodder* is seen occasionally. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pocket+fodder%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQy8iN5MbjAhVvmK0KHaZ0CQ4Q_AUIEigC&biw=1093&bih=500#imgrc=0ezbJXHJMtNI0M:

Comment: People who take their preparedness seriously go with ‘everyday carry’ or ECD. https://www.reddit.com/r/everydaycarry/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app

Comment: "Personal effects" is fairly accurate and not archaic, IMHO.

Comment: "_Persoanl possessions_" is an alternative to "_personal effects_". This is often the term heard in TV drama "The victim had a book amongst his personal possessions"

Comment: I'd just go with "everyday items"—that will be most clearly and readily understood.

Comment: I would say "the junk in my pockets".

Comment: *Personal effects* is not archaic, but it is a much broader concept than what the OP has in mind. It appears that the OP is seeking a term for a subset of personal effects: the small objects that one ordinarily carries in one's pocket or purse.

Comment: Commonly carried everyday items that would also include dish soap, towels, forks etc...  Crikey, I'd love to see the boot (trunk) of your car!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a community of people who use the term [everyday carry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyday_carry) or "EDC" to describe this very idea.

Comment: I first encountered this with respect to knives, but it’s much broader than that. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyday_carry. Why not include this in the answer?

Comment: This point has already been made by @Spagirl in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

A french term: "accoutrement" would be exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

## **paraphernalia**

> all the objects needed for or connected with a particular activity.
>   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paraphernalia

Comment: I can't help but look at this and think....drugs.

Answer (score 0):

'**Bits and Bobs**'

I believe the original version of this idiom is "bits and bobs". It means the same as "odds and ends", which means "bits and pieces, remnants, leftovers". A "bit" was a coin (three-penny bit) and a "bob" was a shilling or twelve pence (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+bits+and+bobs).https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4942/bibs-and-bobs-what-does-it-mean-and-where-does-it-come-from

Backing up a bit, “bits and bobs” does not have its own entry in the Oxford English Dictionary, but is included in a larger entry for various expressions that include “bit.” It’s lumped with “bits and pieces” (very familiar to Americans) and “bits and bats” (not so) and defined as “fragments, oddments, odds and ends; small articles, personal belongings, bric-à-brac.” The first citation is an entry in A Warwickshire Word-book, 1896, which gave a sample sentence: “Gather up your bits-and-bobs, and let me lay the tea.” https://notoneoffbritishisms.com/2018/03/23/bits-and-bobs/